# VB.NET Error when downloading xlsx file from varbinary

Tags: sql-server-2008, download, vb.net-2010, xlsx

I am trying to download a xlsx stored as varbinary in sql server 2008R2

```
Dim command2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT data FROM DocsTable WHERE ID = '" & Id.ToString() & "' ", con)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.xlsx")
Dim command6 As New SqlCommand("SELECT DATALENGTH(data) FROM DocsTable WHERE ID = '" & Id.ToString() & "' ", con)
Dim length As String = command6.ExecuteScalar()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length)
Response.BinaryWrite(dr(0))
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

When I try to open, the open the downloaded file, Excel slaps me with an error
*Excel found unreadable content in 'Test.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this  workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes*

```
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error063040_01.xml</logFileName>
     <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\irstudent\Downloads\Test.xlsx'</summary>
     <additionalInfo><info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info></additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

I compared the contents of the original file and download file for text difference like junk characters but couldnt find any

Comment: Was there a difference between the two files? Maybe if you post the contents of two small sample files illustrating the difference, someone can help.

Comment: There was no difference, i checked it using text diff